# C++ Dll linking Curl

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I am trying to create a dll which uses the curl library for a very simple function. Everything works just fine, the only problem is, that the curl linking does not seem to work properly.

I use the same linking, preprocessordefines and include directories like in my executable project where it works just fine so i am pretty sure it´s not about my linking or binary files of the libary.

Are there any special properties to link a libary to a dll?

My minimal sample code:

C++ Mainfile:

```
#include "main.h" 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Info.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>  
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>

namespace CurlDll 
{ 

    void CallHost::Try() 
    { 
        curlpp::Easy request;
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::UserAgent("Mozilla/4.0"));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::AutoReferer(true));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::FollowLocation(true));
        request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("http://xml.utrace.de"));
        request.perform();
        MessageBox(0,"lololowwwwwwwwwwwl", "wqgqwwwwwgq", MB_OK |MB_ICONINFORMATION); 
    } 
}   
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason)
{return 1;}
```

Header file:

```
#ifdef MAIN_EXPORTS 
#define MAIN_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else 
#define MAIN_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif 
#include <iostream> 


namespace CurlDll 
{ 

    class CallHost 
    { 
    public: 
        static MAIN_API void Try(); 
    }; 
}
```

i get following linking errors @drescherjm
(47 , i will just post a few, i think that shouls be enough)

> ERROR 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external Symbol
>   "__imp__WSAStartup@8".
>
> ERROR   11    error LNK2001: unresolved  external  Symbol
>   "__imp__WSAGetLastError@0".
>
> ERROR   33    error LNK2001: unresolved  external Symbol
>   "__imp__setsockopt@20".

Comment: Please be more specific; when you say "does not seem to work properly" - do you get compilation errors, linker errors, runtime errors? Can you post any error messages you are seeing. The EXE should be able to find the DLL in the search path; typically, they'll be in the same folder.

Comment: `Are there any special properties to link a libary to a dll?` Make sure the DLL was compiled with the same compiler that you use and the same configuration. This avoids any problems with having incompatible CRTs and more than 1 heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker errors are telling you that the linker cannot find definitions for these functions: `WSAStartup`, `WSAGetLastError`, `setsockopt`. These functions are defined in the import library `Ws2_32.lib`. You need to supply that import library to the linker.

This information is given in the documentation for the functions. For instance, the documentation for [`WSAStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213.aspx). At the bottom of the documentation topic is a table listing requirements. Note the required library, `Ws2_32.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols WSAStartup, WSAGetLastError and setsocketopt are part of the Windows API, in Ws2_32.lib (e.g. see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) )

You should include ws2_32.lib as an additional library when you link your DLL. If you're using Visual Studio, it's likely that the search path should already find it; just add it as an additional library.

So actually, I suspect you're not using the *exact* same linker options compared to your .exe

If you're building a .exe or a .dll, the linker needs to ensure it can resolve ALL known symbols at link time.